# SMI gives compilation error while try to compile MIB file from SNMP4j library through java application

Tags: mib, snmp4j, snmp-trap

I have been tried to compile a MIB file through SMI which is used in SNMP4j library in my java application.

Let me share SNMP4j version and MIB file which i have tried to compile and compilations error.

please suggest me to resolve the compilation issue.

SNMP4J version :2.5.11

Compilation error I have got while compile :

```
[CompilationResult{fileName='\opt\dist\OamManager\conf\mib\10892.mib', moduleNames=null, smiErrorList=[SmiError{moduleName='\opt\dist\OamManager\conf\mib\10892.mib', errorNumber=1000, message='[\opt\dist\OamManager\conf\mib\10892.mib] [1000]: Syntax error: Encountered "DellUnsigned32BitRange ::= Gauge" at line 97, column 1:
Was expecting one of:
<LOWERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "OBJECT-TYPE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "TRAP-TYPE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "MODULE-COMPLIANCE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "OBJECT-GROUP" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "OBJECT-IDENTITY" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> <OID> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "NOTIFICATION-GROUP" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "SEQUENCE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "TEXTUAL-CONVENTION" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "AGENT-CAPABILITIES" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "INTEGER" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Integer32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <OCTETSTRING> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <OID> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "BITS" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "IpAddress" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Gauge32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Unsigned32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "TimeTicks" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Opaque" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Counter64" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Counter32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <LOWERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <UPPERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Integer64" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Unsigned64" ...
  ', shortMessage='Syntax error: Was expecting one of: <LOWERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "OBJECT-TYPE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "TRAP-TYPE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "MODULE-COMPLIANCE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "OBJECT-GROUP" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "OBJECT-IDENTITY" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> <OID> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "NOTIFICATION-GROUP" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "SEQUENCE" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "TEXTUAL-CONVENTION" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "AGENT-CAPABILITIES" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "INTEGER" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Integer32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <OCTETSTRING> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <OID> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "BITS" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "IpAddress" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Gauge32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Unsigned32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "TimeTicks" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Opaque" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Counter64" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Counter32" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <LOWERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" <UPPERCASENAME> ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Integer64" ...
  <UPPERCASENAME> "::=" "Unsigned64" ...
   instead of "DellUnsigned32BitRange ::= Gauge"', column=1, row=97, endColumn=41, endRow=97, position=4355, defectiveText='DellUnsigned32BitRange ::= Gauge', expectedText=[, , , , , , , , , "SEQUENCE" , "TEXTUAL-CONVENTION" , , "INTEGER" , "Integer32" , <OCTETSTRING> , <OID> , "BITS" , "IpAddress" , "Gauge32" , "Unsigned32" , "TimeTicks" , "Opaque" , "Counter64" , "Counter32" , <LOWERCASENAME> , <UPPERCASENAME> , "Integer64" , "Unsigned64" ]}, SmiError{moduleName='\opt\dist\OamManager\conf\mib\10892.mib', errorNumber=1020, message='[\opt\dist\OamManager\conf\mib\10892.mib] [1020]: The identifier deviceTypeIsDDR4 at line 8,295, column 5 is ambiguous (RFC2578 §3.1)', shortMessage='The identifier deviceTypeIsDDR4 is ambiguous (RFC2578 §3.1)', column=5, row=8295, endColumn=20, endRow=8295, position=381270, defectiveText='deviceTypeIsDDR4', expectedText=[<LOWERCASENAME> ]}], zipFileName='null'}]
```